# Why is one of my three graph lines compressed?

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter

I have a python code which plots sensor data in Tkinter. It worked perfect but just recently it produced something very weird and i don't know what the cause is/was. It was the only time it happened and i cant explain why. Maybe someone has an idea why.
[image: my three graphs for the sensor]

Here is my code for plotting the data:

```
fig = plt.figure() #Init of fig and ax
ax1 = plt.subplot(3, 1, 1)
ax2 = plt.subplot(3, 1, 2, sharex = ax1)
ax3 = plt.subplot(3, 1, 3, sharex = ax1)
```

I use a canvas for the diagrams:

```
self.canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, self)
self.canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=tk.TOP, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)

toolbar = NavigationToolbar2Tk(self.canvas, self)
toolbar.update()
self.canvas._tkcanvas.pack(side=tk.TOP, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)
```

Method for plotting data:

```
def plot_data(self): # plot data which got appended into lists
        ax1.clear()
        ax2.clear()
        ax3.clear()
        ax1.set_title("Acceleration data from " + self.timestr)
        #plt.ylabel("y", rotation = 0)
        ax1.set_ylabel("x-axis [g]")
        ax2.set_ylabel("y-axis [g]")
        ax3.set_ylabel("z-axis [g]")
        ax3.set_xlabel("ms")
        ax1.plot(self.x_graph, self.y1_graph, "k")
        ax2.plot(self.x_graph, self.y2_graph, "k")
        ax3.plot(self.x_graph, self.y3_graph, "k")
        self.canvas.draw_idle()
```

Comment: Does the issue persist if you initialise all subplots at once: `fig, (ax1, ax2, ax3) = plt.subplots(3, 1, sharex=True)`?

Comment: Also, what happens if you set `expand=False`?

Comment: Like i said it happened only once. it could have been a bug. I always initialized the subplots the same and it worked all the time except for that one instance

Comment: it was just very weird to see and i wondered if i made a mistake

Comment: if i change `self.canvas.get_tk_widget` `expand=False` it seems like nothing happens. If i change `self.canvas._tkcanvas.pack` the toolbar gets substantially bigger

Comment: If the issue is not easily reproducible, it will be very difficult to debug and all my suggested code changes are probably useless.

Comment: Yeah i'm sorry, i thought maybe someone experienced something similar. I guess its a bug i wont be able to fix. Since it happened only once in maybe a 100 tries i don't think i can do anything about it. Thanks anyways for your messages

Comment: it would be simpler if you would create `minimal working code with example data in code` - and then we could copy and test it.

Comment: hey i just got around to cutting the code to minimal form. Its in the EDIT in the main post